# How to prevent escaping of carriage returns in DOMText?

Tags: php, dom

Is it possible to prevent the escaping of carriage returns in DOMText?

The following prints `&#13;`:

```
$d = new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');
$t = $d->createTextNode("\r");
echo $d->saveXML($t);
```

Other unprintable characters don't get escaped. This is the only character in the single byte ASCII range that gets escaped as a numeric entity. Nul bytes seem to break the text, but `\1` through `0x12` are kept literal.

I note also that the JavaScript DOM allows the raw `\r` character, so presumably it's not an invalid byte. In Chrome, the following prints true:

```
var p = document.createElement('p')
p.appendChild( document.createTextNode('\r') );
console.log( '\r' === p.innerHTML );
```

I'm not interested in workarounds. I just want to know if there's some way to control this directly when calling saveXML.

Answer (score -1):

try using this method `createElement` instead of `createTextNode`. The `createTextNode` also escapes the string that you pass as a parameter, the other one does not

Comment: That's not correct. `$d->saveXML( $d->createElement('p',"\r") )` prints `<p>&#13;</p>`. Plus createElement can't handle some characters that should be escaped.